# click on div one, remove class from dive two and paste to div two new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqwTB/) but it´s now working, why is that?

HTML:

```
<div class="run"></div>
<div class="s"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Append class to contact
    $('.run').click(function () {
        $("div.s").removeClass("s");
        $(this).addClass("bez");
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery. There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sCBN7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simply not included the **jQuery** file from the checkbox in the left hand side from the `Frameworks & Extensions` option.

Just select the latest **jQuery** file from the checkbox and it should work.